# does not have install to iOS 5.1 simulator in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode

I upgrade Xcode from 4.4.1 to 4.5, but when I install iOS 5.1 Simulator, an error occurs: "does not have access to iOS 5.1 simulator". There is a solution here But, I don't know how to accept the new developer agreement?

Any body can help me? 
thanks. in Advance,[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accept the new developer agreement, go to http://developer.apple.com/ios and log in with your account.

**IF** (and only if) you are the team agent (i.e. the owner of the account), you should see a yellow box that says something like "in order to continue access to blah blah blah, you need to agree to this new lengthly unreadable contract" with a link in it).

If you are not the team agent (or owner), then you need to have that person do it for you.

And once that's finished, you should able to download additional resources via the Xcode "download" preference pane.